# Bounce animation for custom view drawn with canvas

Tags: android, animation, canvas

I am drawing different view in a custom view with canvas, and want to add custom animation to on of the view (infinite bounce) not sure how this can be achieved. Would appreciate any suggestions. Here is block of code and I want to add bounce animation to view1

```
class MainView extends View {
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();

            // Draw view 1
            canvas.translate(…);
            view1.draw(canvas)

            // draw other views

        canvas.restore();
    }
}

class View1 extends View {
..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add animators directly to Views using either XML or Java. To create the bounce you would extend the interpolator class (or one of the predefined subclasses)